# Adding href to Excel Export C#

Tags: c#, excel, datatable, excelpackage

I need help with this issue, I'm exporting my datatable into an excel file which works fine. the problem is I'm trying to make one of the columns a hyperlink to a document but as it starts to build out the excel file I get this error. Thank you in advance for your help.

'This operation is not supported for a relative URI.'

```
using OfficeOpenXml;
using OfficeOpenXml.Table;

public void ExportExcelFile(System.Data.DataTable excelData, string excelSheetName)
    {
        using (var package = new ExcelPackage())
        {
            ExcelWorksheet ws = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(excelSheetName);

            int rowCount = 1;
            foreach (DataRow rw in excelData.Rows)
            {
                //excelData.Columns.RemoveAt(0);
                rowCount += 1;
                for (int i = 1; i < excelData.Columns.Count + 1; i++)
                {
                    // Add the header the first time through 
                    if (rowCount == 2)
                    {
                        ws.Row(1).Style.Font.Bold = true;
                        ws.Cells[1, i].Value = excelData.Columns[i - 1].ColumnName;
                    }
                    ws.Column(i).AutoFit();

                    //THIS IS THTE PROBLEM
                    string hyperlink = "<a href='~/Documents/DownloadFile.aspx?id=" + rw["DocPk"].ToString() + "'>" + rw["Drawing Id"].ToString() + "</a>";
                    ws.Cells[i, 7].Hyperlink = new Uri(hyperlink, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);  

                    ws.Cells[rowCount, i].Value = rw[i - 1].ToString();
                }
            }

            MemoryStream Result = new MemoryStream();
            package.SaveAs(Result);
            Response.ClearContent();
            Response.OutputStream.Write(Result.GetBuffer(), 0, Result.GetBuffer().Length);
            Response.OutputStream.Flush();
            Response.OutputStream.Close();
            byte[] byteArray = Result.ToArray();
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + excelSheetName + ".xlsx");
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", byteArray.Length.ToString());
            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
            Response.BinaryWrite(byteArray);
            Response.End();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What this means is that you need an absolute path instead of using the ~/ notation. Is it possible for you to use an absolute? It makes sense that you couldn't use a relative path since you're trying to export to a spreadsheet which likely has no way of getting your root directory. Maybe you can get the root for each hyperlink and concatenate??

Comment: Yes, I thought that was the issue and I replaced the notation with the site url plus location and parameters but I am still getting the same error.  string hyperlink = "<a href='http://sitename.com/Documents/DownloadFile.aspx?id=" + rw["DocPk"].ToString() + "'>" + rw["Drawing Id"].ToString() + "</a>"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Excel simply doesn't support relative URLs, as an Excel document doesn't have a URL to be relative *to*.  You'll need to fully qualify all your URLs:

```
string hyperlink = String.Format("http://{0}/Documents/DownloadFile.aspx?id={1}",
   Page.Request.Url.Host,
   rw["DocPk"].ToString());

ws.Cells[rowCount, i].Hyperlink = new Uri(hyperlink, UriKind.Absolute);
ws.Cells[rowCount, i].Value = rw["Drawing Id"];
```

Note the fully qualified URL, complete with *http://* as well as the `UriKind.Absolute`.

Comment: I made a couple of changes but I am still getting an error on ws.Cells[rowCount, i].Hyperlink = new Uri(hyperlink, UriKind.Absolute); The formatting of the (string) hyperlink is as you have recommended

Comment: You're still getting the same error, even though you use `UriKind.Absolute`?  That's odd!  I'm afraid I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Here is the solution to the issue:  var hyperlink = String.Format("Http://" + Page.Request.Url.Host + "/Documents/DownloadFile.aspx?id={0}", rw["DocPk"].ToString());
                           
                          ws.Cells[rowCount, i].Hyperlink = new Uri(hyperlink, UriKind.Absolute);
                          ws.Cells[rowCount, i].Style.Font.UnderLine = true;
                          ws.Cells[rowCount, i].Style.Font.Color.SetColor(System.Drawing.Color.Blue);
                          ws.Cells[rowCount, i].Value = rw["Drawing Id"];

Answer (score 1):

Here is the fixed and working solution, Thanks Mike for helping get me pointed in the right direction

```
    public void ExportExcelFile(System.Data.DataTable excelData, string excelSheetName)
    {
        using (var package = new ExcelPackage())
        {
            ExcelWorksheet ws = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(excelSheetName);
            HtmlAnchor lnkOpen = new HtmlAnchor();
            int rowCount = 1;
            foreach (DataRow rw in excelData.Rows)
            {

                rowCount += 1;
                for (int i = 1; i < excelData.Columns.Count + 1; i++)
                {
                    // Add the header the first time through 
                    if (rowCount == 2)
                    {
                        ws.Row(1).Style.Font.Bold = true;
                        ws.Cells[1, i].Value = excelData.Columns[i - 1].ColumnName;
                    }
                    ws.Column(i).AutoFit();

                    if (excelData.Columns[i - 1].ColumnName.ToString() == "Drawing Id" )
                    {
                     //var hyperlink = String.Format("Http://" + Page.Request.Url.Host + "/Documents/DownloadFile.aspx?id={0}", rw["DocPk"].ToString());
                     var hyperlink = String.Format(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DocumentManagerURL"] + "Documents/DownloadFile.aspx?id={0}", rw["DocPk"].ToString());
                      ws.Cells[rowCount, i].Hyperlink = new Uri(hyperlink, UriKind.Absolute);
                      ws.Cells[rowCount, i].Style.Font.UnderLine = true;
                      ws.Cells[rowCount, i].Style.Font.Color.SetColor(System.Drawing.Color.Blue);
                      ws.Cells[rowCount, i].Value = rw["Drawing Id"]; 

                    }
                    else{
                      ws.Cells[rowCount, i].Value = rw[i - 1].ToString();  
                    }

                }
                //excelData.Columns.RemoveAt(7);
            }

            MemoryStream Result = new MemoryStream();
            package.SaveAs(Result);
            Response.ClearContent();
            Response.OutputStream.Write(Result.GetBuffer(), 0, Result.GetBuffer().Length);
            Response.OutputStream.Flush();
            Response.OutputStream.Close();
            byte[] byteArray = Result.ToArray();
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + excelSheetName + ".xlsx");
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", byteArray.Length.ToString());
            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
            Response.BinaryWrite(byteArray);
            Response.End();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally able to fix my issue ..Thanks a lot 
        Using Excelv As New ExcelPackage()

```
        Dim ws As ExcelWorksheet = Excelv.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(fileName)

        Dim rowCount As Integer = 1
        For Each rw As DataRow In dddd.Rows
            'excelData.Columns.RemoveAt(0);
            rowCount += 1
            For i As Integer = 1 To dddd.Columns.Count
                ' Add the header the first time through 
                If rowCount = 2 Then
                    'ws.Row(1).Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(Color.Azure)
                    ws.Row(1).Style.Font.Bold = True
                    'ws.Row(1).Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(Color.AliceBlue)
                    '  ws.Row(1).Style.Color = "#FFFFFF"
                    If dddd.Columns(i - 1).ColumnName = ("ID") Then
                        'ws.Cells(1, i).Value = dddd.Columns(i - 1).ColumnName
                    ElseIf dddd.Columns(i - 1).ColumnName = ("Plant_Description") Then
                        ws.Cells(1, i).Value = "Plant"
                    ElseIf dddd.Columns(i - 1).ColumnName = ("Report_No") Then
                        ws.Cells(1, i).Value = "Scrap Number"
                    ElseIf dddd.Columns(i - 1).ColumnName = ("Req_Emp_Name") Then
                        ws.Cells(1, i).Value = "Originator"
                    ElseIf dddd.Columns(i - 1).ColumnName = ("ScrapItem_Desc") Then
                        ws.Cells(1, i).Value = "Item"
                    ElseIf dddd.Columns(i - 1).ColumnName = ("Info_ID") Then
                        ws.Cells(1, i).Value = "NO"
                    ElseIf dddd.Columns(i - 1).ColumnName = ("Itemdesc") Then
                        ws.Cells(1, i).Value = "ItemDesc"
                    ElseIf dddd.Columns(i - 1).ColumnName = ("Part_No") Then
                        ws.Cells(1, i).Value = "Part No"
                    ElseIf dddd.Columns(i - 1).ColumnName = ("quantity") Then
                        ws.Cells(1, i).Value = "Quantity"
                    ElseIf dddd.Columns(i - 1).ColumnName = ("STD_Cost") Then
                        ws.Cells(1, i).Value = "UnitPrice"
                    ElseIf dddd.Columns(i - 1).ColumnName = ("Total_Cost") Then
                        ws.Cells(1, i).Value = "UnitTotal"
                    ElseIf dddd.Columns(i - 1).ColumnName = ("Close_DateTime") Then
                        ws.Cells(1, i).Value = "Close Date"
                    ElseIf dddd.Columns(i - 1).ColumnName = ("Doc_Create_Date") Then
                        ws.Cells(1, i).Value = "Submit Date"
                    Else
                        ws.Cells(1, i).Value = dddd.Columns(i - 1).ColumnName
                    End If

                End If
                ws.Column(i).AutoFit()
                'ws.Column("ID").Hidden = True
                'THIS IS THTE PROBLEM
                'Dim hyperlink As String = "<a href='~/Documents/DownloadFile.aspx?id=" + rw("ID").ToString() + "'>" + rw("ID").ToString() + "</a>"
                'ws.Cells(i, 7).Hyperlink = New Uri(hyperlink, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)

                'ws.Cells(rowCount, i).Value = rw(i - 1).ToString()

                'Dim hyperlink As String = [String].Format("http://{0}/Documents/DownloadFile.aspx?id={1}", Page.Request.Url.Host, rw("ID").ToString())

                'ws.Cells(rowCount, i).Hyperlink = New Uri(hyperlink, UriKind.Absolute)
                'ws.Cells(rowCount, i).Value = rw("Drawing Id")


                If dddd.Columns(i - 1).ColumnName.ToString() = "Month" Then
                    'var hyperlink = String.Format("Http://" + Page.Request.Url.Host + "/Documents/DownloadFile.aspx?id={0}", rw["DocPk"].ToString());
                    Dim hyperlink = [String].Format("your url" + "{0}", rw("ID").ToString())
                    ws.Cells(rowCount, i).Hyperlink = New Uri(hyperlink, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)
                    ws.Cells(rowCount, i).Style.Font.UnderLine = True
                    ws.Cells(rowCount, i).Style.Font.Color.SetColor(System.Drawing.Color.Blue)

                    ws.Cells(rowCount, i).Value = rw("Month")
                Else
                    If dddd.Columns(i - 1).ColumnName = ("ID") Then
                    ElseIf dddd.Columns(i - 1).ColumnName = ("Plant_Description") Then
                        ws.Cells(rowCount, i).Value = rw(i - 1).ToString()
                    ElseIf dddd.Columns(i - 1).ColumnName = ("Report_No") Then
                        ws.Cells(rowCount, i).Value = rw(i - 1).ToString()
                    ElseIf dddd.Columns(i - 1).ColumnName = ("Req_Emp_Name") Then
                        ws.Cells(rowCount, i).Value = rw(i - 1).ToString()
                    ElseIf dddd.Columns(i - 1).ColumnName = ("ScrapItem_Desc") Then
                        ws.Cells(rowCount, i).Value = rw(i - 1).ToString()
                    ElseIf dddd.Columns(i - 1).ColumnName = ("Info_ID") Then
                        ws.Cells(rowCount, i).Value = Convert.ToInt32(rw(i - 1).ToString())
                    ElseIf dddd.Columns(i - 1).ColumnName = ("Itemdesc") Then
                        ws.Cells(rowCount, i).Value = rw(i - 1).ToString()
                    ElseIf dddd.Columns(i - 1).ColumnName = ("Part_No") Then
                        ws.Cells(rowCount, i).Value = rw(i - 1).ToString()
                    ElseIf dddd.Columns(i - 1).ColumnName = ("quantity") Then
                        ws.Cells(rowCount, i).Value = Convert.ToDecimal(rw(i - 1).ToString())
                    ElseIf dddd.Columns(i - 1).ColumnName = ("STD_Cost") Then
                        ws.Cells(rowCount, i).Value = Convert.ToDecimal(rw(i - 1).ToString())
                    ElseIf dddd.Columns(i - 1).ColumnName = ("Total_Cost") Then
                        ws.Cells(rowCount, i).Value = Convert.ToDecimal(rw(i - 1).ToString())
                    ElseIf dddd.Columns(i - 1).ColumnName = ("Close_DateTime") Then
                        ws.Cells(rowCount, i).Value = rw(i - 1).ToString()
                    ElseIf dddd.Columns(i - 1).ColumnName = ("Doc_Create_Date") Then
                        ws.Cells(rowCount, i).Value = rw(i - 1).ToString()
                    Else
                        ws.Cells(1, i).Value = dddd.Columns(i - 1).ColumnName
                    End If
                    'ws.Cells(rowCount, i).Value = rw(i - 1).ToString()
                End If
            Next
        Next

        Dim Result As New MemoryStream()

        Excelv.SaveAs(Result)
        Response.ClearContent()
        Response.OutputStream.Write(Result.GetBuffer(), 0, Result.GetBuffer().Length)
        Response.OutputStream.Flush()
        Response.OutputStream.Close()
        Dim byteArray As Byte() = Result.ToArray()
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName + ".xlsx")
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", byteArray.Length.ToString())
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
        Response.BinaryWrite(byteArray)
        Response.[End]()

    End Using
```